# Map с n -ым количеством v

Tags: map, java

Есть ли такой?

p.s. похожий эффект можно добиться как-то так:

```
Map<Integer,Integer[]> map;
map.set(1, (new Integer[n]) ); //то самое n
```

Но как-то не очень удобно выходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам скорее всего нужен `Multimap`. Встроенного решения нету, но Oracle предлагает по сути то же, что и вы, только у них `List` вместо массива (смотрите [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), пролистайте вниз до Multimaps).

---

Также есть много 3rdparty-имплементаций, легко [гуглятся](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+multimap).

Comment: Да вроде оно, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Кстати можно объяснить почему не массив, а лист. Если v будут разных типов - массив не спасёт

Comment: Ну, можно на крайняк `Object[]`.

Но: в List можно добавлять элементы постепенно, а с массивом надо заранее знать, сколько их будет.